# how to filter a django queryset where the conditions are taken from another list?

Tags: python, django, models

I have a situation where i have a list of primary keys. And i need to filter(OR) a queryset using the primarykeys in the list.

But the problem is that the list is dynamic.

Is there any way i can filter the queryset by doing an OR using each primary keys on the queryset.

Comment: Have you tried [in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe `in` will help https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in

Answer (score 0):

This should help you: [in_bulk](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in-bulk)

Comment: no its not objects its queryset. Any way thanks for replying.